# Hardware acceleration on the pi 4

Tags: pi-4, gpu

From what I found on the web, people seem to be having issues with hardware acceleration on the pi 4 running Buster (CPU does the decoding instead of GPU). Is hardware acceleration not supported? If it's not, why? Will it be supported in the next release of Raspbian? And what about the H.265 hardware decoder, is that supported or will it ever be?

Comment: what makes you believe the GPU is not doing its job?

Comment: I've seen issues with older versions of Rasbian that caused the hardware acceleration not to work at all (if the corresponding option in the config was enabled, the minecraft demo would not start), but after a recent driver update, everything seems to be fine.

Comment: Quote: "*From what I found on the web, people seem to be having issues with hardware acceleration*". Where do you found it on the web?

Comment: I saw some YouTube videos and forum posts. I guess the Raspbian developers disabled hardware acceleration after finding a bug, but it looks like it's been enabled in the latest release

Comment: But I believe the H.265 hardware decoder is still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The foundation has their own (downstream) version of ffmpeg with HEVC decode (!) acceleration:

https://github.com/popcornmix/FFmpeg/tree/2711

HEVC acceleration in VLC is currently being beta tested :
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=257395

I suppose patches for Chromium will come after that ...